# Performance issue while retrieving the records from Oracle DB using Hibernate HQL

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am working on retrieving the 40K records from Oracle DB using Hibernate HQL.

It's taking 3 seconds of time to fetch 40K records from DB. Same query I had run it in SQL developer and it's taking 0.5 sec for the same query.

Can anyone please suggest the better approach to get the records in less time?

Comment: What are you doing, after you fetch those 40k records? There are a lot of workarounds, depends on what are you doing with the data. If its just to fetch data and show it to the user, i doubt, that he will want so se the ALL 40k records. Suggest the user to provide specified search criteria to speed up the data retrieval. Other case, when you need to aggregate or somehow process the data, create one specified DB procedure, where it retrieves and process data (in one DB call). And so on.

Comment: What we are doing is, we are screening(comparing) the 40k (customer data) records with other data based on some rules. If the data matches, we are displaying the matching data to user. While fetching this 40K records from DB it's taking the time.  We are using the fetch type as LAZY and HQL to retrieve these records. Is it having any alternative procedure to get the data quickly.

Comment: The comparing is done where? In java? With your description, it all can be done with one select with exists clause (rules, to distinguish matching data). Data compering in DB is much faster, then in Java. Wrap all the logic in one DB procedure. If you are working with Oracle DB, you should have access to it (unless you are front/back-end developer, so pass the task to Oracle Developer)

Comment: We had written one algorithm  for comparing. After getting the 40K records, the comparison of this data with other going smooth only. The problem was to getting these bulk data from data base only. we had tried with HQL and Native sql and applied Scroll as Read_Only and Forward_Only but there is no difference in fetch time. We have laces of data in database and we are retrieving the data by batch wise to setting the records count as 40K for each batch. Initially it's taking 3 sec of time and later it's taking 9 to 11 sec to fetch these records from database.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the display of query in hibernate to ON
like
    true

Then verify that you have the same request as typed in SQLDev window
Note that join(s) and where statements orders  must be the same.
If it's not your case try to modify the HQL

Comment: The query was same which I had run in SQLDev and HQL and we tried with Native SQL also, But there is no difference in time.